# Loading Large Bitmaps fails

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I got problems with the recommended way of loading large bitmaps. 
I've simply gone by the guide provided by Google themself.
But I can't get it to work, when I try to upload the bitmap to my backend I get returned that the bitmap is null:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getHeight()' on a null object reference

I can upload bitmaps that haven't been created by this method without problems, so it's definitely something in the Bitmap creation that is causing it. I haven't changed anything besides the fact that the method decodes a Stream instead of a Resource.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromStream(InputStream stream, Rect padding,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    //BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream,padding,options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream,padding,options);
}

public void attachProfilePhoto(Uri uri){

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;


    InputStream stream;
    try {

        stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

        Bitmap bitmap = decodeBitmapFromStream(stream,null,300,300);

        //Bitmap image_scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 500 * bitmap.getHeight() / bitmap.getWidth(), false);

        uploadImage(bitmap, "image1");
        Picasso.with(this).load(uri).into(profile_image);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Android Universal Image Loader`. worked even with a 50mb JPG file!

Comment: `recommended way of loading large bitmaps`. Loading in what? `upload the bitmap to my backend`. That looks something completely different to me. Cannot you be clear about what you want?

Comment: If `decodeBitmapFromStream()` returns a null then do not try to upload a null bitmap. Before check if bitmap==null.

Comment: That having said: completely wrong code if you have an url to an image then do not use Bitmap and BitmapFactory to upload that image.